# How to write conditional statement in swift correctly?

Tags: swift, conditional-statements

I am new in swift and based on ios developer library I found this conditional statement code:

```
if *condition 1* {
    *statements to execute if condition 1 is true*
} else if *condition 2* {
    *statements to execute if condition 2 is true*
} else {
    *statements to execute if both conditions are false*
}
```

But what I want something like this :

```
 if *condition 1* {
    *statements to execute if condition 1 is true*
} else {
    *statements to execute if condition 1 is false*
} 
 if *condition 2* {
    *statements to execute if condition 2 is true*
} else {
    *statements to execute if condition 2 is false*
} 
 if *condition 3* {
    *statements to execute if condition 3 is true*
} else {
    *statements to execute if condition 3 is false*
} 
 if *condition 4* {
    *statements to execute if condition 4 is true*
} else {
    *statements to execute if condition 4 is false*
}
```

Is there any solution to make it right, I am sorry if my question sounds stupid ?

Comment: Your second code block should work exactly as you wrote it, where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I take my suggestion back. I misread the question. Didn't see that there was an else statement for each condition. My bad.

**Original Answer**

It depends on condition complexity, but usually you can use `switch` statement to check for multiple conditions.

From Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html):

> Swift provides two ways to add conditional branches to your code,
>   known as the if statement and the switch statement. Typically, you use
>   the if statement to evaluate simple conditions with only a few
>   possible outcomes. The switch statement is better suited to more
>   complex conditions with multiple possible permutations, and is useful
>   in situations where pattern-matching can help select an appropriate
>   code branch to execute.
>
> A switch statement considers a value and compares it against several
>   possible matching patterns. It then executes an appropriate block of
>   code, based on the first pattern that matches successfully. A switch
>   statement provides an alternative to the if statement for responding
>   to multiple potential states.
>
> In its simplest form, a switch statement compares a value against one
>   or more values of the same type:

```
switch some value to consider {
case value1:
    //respond to value 1
case value2,
value3:
    //respond to value 2 or 3
default:
    //otherwise, do something else
}
```

Comment: A switch statement isn't really good here for what the user is asking.  It'd require a big tuple full of booleans...

Comment: @nhgrif question is about general "condition". That is why I've said that it depends a lot on the condition itself. There's no universal good way. But I'm pretty sure switch statement is designed to deal with multiple conditions as an much easier to read alternative to multiple else if 's.

Comment: @nhgrif just realized I've misread the question. I apologize.